# Vuetify – Expand v-navigation-drawer on click like it works on hover

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

The v-navigation-drawer has a very nice `expand-on-hover` functionality; here the expanded layer is displayed `atop` of the content; i.e. the content is *not resized*. Now I would like to have the same behaviour *on click*; but if I just manipulate the `mini-variant` property then the content gets *resized* (the layer moves the start of the content).

Now I found out – by complete accident – that I (kind of) get the behaviour I want by setting the `width` property (of `v-navigation-drawer`) not to a number (like 224 or "224") but to a string containing the number plus a unit (like "224px").
To me this actually seems to be a bug. Is it? If so: is there a proper way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question would benefit if you helped others to reproduce the problem by including an exemplary code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may want to play with the `temporary`, `app` and `clipped` props - in various combinations until you achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV, unfortunately that did not work for me. I ended up with setting the padding-left of the v-main component to a fixed value for medium devices.